# Execcommand formatblock headings in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I want to format selected text to a heading, the way I am doing it works fine in Firefox and Google Chrome but it doesn't work in IE9, here is how I do it:

```
document.execCommand('formatBlock',false,'h1');
```

Does anyone know how to achieve the same task in Internet Explorer 9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be one of syntax. IE expects the tag to be formatted while the other browsers don't.

See [here](http://help.dottoro.com/larpvnhw.php):

> In Internet Explorer, the name of the element must be placed between
>   tag delimiters (such as `<H1>`). Firefox, Opera, Google Chrome and
>   Safari support all block elements, Internet Explorer supports only the
>   h1 - h6, address and pre elements

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer supports only heading tags `H1` - `H6`, `ADDRESS`, and `PRE`, which must also include the tag delimiters `<` and `>`, such as in `<H1>`.

Answer (score 0):

works perfect for me in IE9

your codes probably wrong, mines more like:

```
        var contentWindow = editor.contentWindow;
        contentWindow.focus();
        contentWindow.document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, '<h1>');
        contentWindow.focus();
```